# Compare two wav files in the frequency domain in java

Tags: java, fft, wav

I have two wav files ( O and X ) as input and i want to find out the similarity between them in the scale [0 - 1] .  This is the formula that i am trying to apply :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dotPM.png

O(t,f) is the magnitude of frequency f at time time slice t for wav file O .

I am doing this in java and used "audio-analysis" library to calculate fft .
How do i apply this algorithm in Java ?

```
float[] samplesa = new float[1024];
float[] samplesb = new float[1024];
WaveDecoder decodera = new WaveDecoder( new FileInputStream( "X.wav" ) );
WaveDecoder decoderb = new WaveDecoder( new FileInputStream( "O.wav" ) );
FFT ffta = new FFT(1024, 44100);
FFT fftb = new FFT(1024, 44100);
while( decodera.readSamples( samplesa ) > 0 )
    {
       ffta.forward(samplesa); 
       decoderb.readSamples( samplesb )
       fftb.forward(samplesb); 
    }
```

Here is the "audio-analysis" library  : http://audio-analysis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: Do you really have to do this in Java?

Comment: This is a part of a bigger project in java ... So yes ... If there are any command line tools that would also suffice as i can invoke them from java ..